# Ignoring Existing Helper Functions in Laravel or Lumen

Tags: php, lumen, spl-autoload-register

In my app I use Lumen for my API which gives me the ability to use any included packages and helpers etc.

The problem is, that my app is already built using a different container. (Pimple, believe me if it was an option to change it all I would)

So I need to build out my own helpers to use in the main part of the app. The API returns before proceeding into and booting the main app so having the Lumen helpers autoloaded in composer is fine for the API.

But, because of this, my helpers file which loads later in the stack can't have any of the same function names as the autoloaded Lumen helpers, and this sucks.

So my question is:

***Is there a way to conditionally ignore, remove, or otherwise not use, existing functions in lieu of my own? Or somehow disable the Lumen helper file that's loaded by composer?***

Any thoughts, help, discussions or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is your app loading code? Surely if your Lumen app is an API, then your other app should just be consuming endpoints. It souldn’t be loading any code, and therefore shouldn’t matter what container your app uses.

Comment: The app includes Lumen as an API for mobile devices in it's own isolated directory. The front index.php file detects a request to the api and pushes that request to Lumen then exits. This is the way the client wants it so it is what it is.  I works really well, I'd just like to refactor a bunch of this to be less coupled.

Comment: If the API code is in its own directory, and served from a different host, then it shouldn’t conflict with your app.

Comment: It's not served from a different host.

Comment: Either split the repositories up, or put them both in separate directories with their own composer.json file and web root.

Comment: Why use one index.php for both applications? I would move lumen into it's own `/api` subdirectory, and modify your existing sites .htaccess so it ignores the `/api` uri. That way lumen will run completely independent of the other application.